# Office 356 API - how to get find to what shared folder an memo item belong to?

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have built an addin that download a selected message in outlook. It works great with user's mailbox, however when it comes to emails in shared folder things are getting complicated.

I'm using following API to download an email

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/users/${sharedfolder-email}/messages/${id}/$value
```

and I can't figure out how to get an ${sharedfolder-email} or ID.

Here is a snippet how I get required data to download email using JavaScript API

```
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync(function(result) {
  if (result.status !== "succeeded") {
    printError(outputEl, "Error happened (accesss token was not issued), try again or contact support");
    return;
  }

var token = result.value;
var ewsurl = Office.context.mailbox.restUrl;
var ewsItemId = Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId;
var isFromSharedFolder = Office.context.mailbox.initialData.isFromSharedFolder
const itemId = Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId(ewsItemId, Office.MailboxEnums.RestVersion.v2_0);
...
}
```

I have a flag isFromSharedFolder that indicate if an item belongs to SharedFolder but I can't find out to what folder it actually belongs.

Do I miss something? Please help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the email address of the Shared Folder, you can use this API:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.getSharedPropertiesAsync
```

This will return an [Office.SharedProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.sharedproperties?view=outlook-js-preview) object that contains the `targetMailbox` which is the email address of the Shared Folder where the item is located.

Further documentation can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/delegate-access?tabs=windows%2Cxmlmanifest

One more thing: `Office.context.mailbox.initialData.isFromSharedFolder` is not an API. Instead, use the `getSharedPropertiesAsync` API.